# Этимология слова "приторный"

Tags: этимология

Считается, что слово "приторный" имеет неясную этимологию. У Фасмера дается не очень понятная статья: указаны диалектные "приторомный, приторомко", упоминается глагол "тереть". У Черных ничего нет. Хотелось бы больше узнать об этимологии и истории употребления этого слова.

Comment: Поговаривают, что слово "приторный" имеет неясную этимологию, что угрожает  безопасности и/или благосостоянию пользователей этого слова.

Comment: Зато  у  этого  слова  практически  одно  значение:  очень  сладко.

Comment: Может  это  профессионализм  -  из  словаря  кулинаров ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно из первых упоминаний в русской литературе :

> Д. И. Фонвизин. К родным (1784-1785)
> **Сперва приторно мне было в одном чану купаться с людьми**, которые больны, господь ведает чем; но теперь к этому привык и знаю, что свойство серной воды ни под каким видом не допустит прилипнуть никакой болезни.

**Притороный.**
1. Тяжкий, мучительный. *... смертью притороною животъ свой скончаеши*.
2. Чересчур насыщенный, густой. *Дух ... сладостенъ, но притороненъ* (Травник 1534).
(СлРЯ 11-17 вв)

**ВЫторить.** Выдержать кого/что в трудных условиях. *Выторился на стуже и хмель прошел*. *Выторить на хлебе и воде*.
**Торный**, неупотр. Приторный. По причине сладимости или излишней здобы неприятный, приедчивый.
(САР 1789-94)

---

Исходный глагол *тОрю* - упражняю кого/что, терпеливо и методично что-то делаю. *Торная дорога* - протоптанная, сглаженная, удобная. *Проторити* - израсходовать, поиздержаться; *протор* - расход, убыток или приход, приобретение; *проторный* - связанный с расходами... Уже отсюда, вероятно, новое расширение смысла : **приторный**, то есть излишний, избыточный, слишком насыщенный.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Где вы только находите такие интересные сведения, поделитесь ссылками. Но вот какой остался вопрос:  приторный соотносится с "проторенный" и в конечном счете с "тереть", торить - это долго повторять, долго выдерживать? Каково самое общее значение корня?

Comment: СлРЯ 11-17вв  
http://nadpisi-dr-rusi.livejournal.com/3871.html  
САР 1789-94  
http://imwerden.de/  
(искать "САР 1789-94" поиском)  
Общее значение корня : ищу пока)

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё одно новгородское словечко "притор", что значит болотистое, вязкое место (по Далю). Вязкое, значит густое, густое значит чересчур чем-то насыщенное, чересчур чем-то насыщенное — значит избыточное.

В этом смысле и используется слово "приторный". Чересчур густой дым там или чересчур слажённый пирог.